# How to write a function into a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.2

How would one answer this foor loop question using proper python syntax:

```
def int_all_2(str_list):
    '''(list of str) -> NoneType
    Replace every str element of str_list with its corresponding
    int version.
    For example,
    >>> sl = ['100', '222', '2', '34']
    >>> int_all_2(sl)
    >>> sl
    [100, 222, 2, 34]
    '''
```

Would it be like this?

```
l = []
  for x in str_list:
    l.append (int_all_2(x))
    return l
```

Comment: Please format the code properly. Also, if you have a possible solution already then could you not just try if it works?

Comment: Assuming your list ONLY contains numeric integer strings: `l = [int(itm) for itm in str_list]`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert each element of the list to integer and then return a new list you can use **map** function :

```
def strs2ints(l):
   return map(int,l)
```

You should also note that function strs2ints **doesn't** change the contents of array l.

In case you want to change the contents of the original array l, which I do not recommend(you should prefer using "clean" functions over functions with side-effects) you can try the following code :

```
def strs2ints(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
       l[i] = int(l[i])
```

Comment: Thanks so much it makes perfect sense now!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your list contains only string representation of numeric integers, you don't even need a function, just list comprehension:

```
l = [int(itm) for itm in str_list]
```

If you want to ignore possible strings:

```
l = [int(itm) for itm in str_list if not itm.isalpha]
```

Or, if you *require* a function:

```
def int_all(str_list):
    return [int(itm) for itm in str_list]
```